The amount of RAM was not the same
Why Ram Value is not the same in neofetch and setting




What difference are we supposed to be seeing here?

In neofetch My Memory is 8GB! But my Laptop Ram is 20GB

Your neofetch output isn't complete. There's clearly more to the side. Or do you think your resolution is 1920x and your GPU is Intel UHD Gr as well?

The amount of memory shown in the Neofetch pic is used memory, total memory is cropped from the image.
